# How do I create a Macro/short cuts in Eclipse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, macros

How do I create a Macro in Eclipse?
For example: I want the combination alt+s will print on the page

```
//********************************************************************
```

Answer (score 10):

In Java there's the option to create a code template. Like writing sysout + CTRL + space generates System.out.println() text.

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates

This option seems to be available for several other programming languages.

Is not exactly what you are looking for, since it works with written text but it's usable for your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to do that on Eclipse, however you can use a simple [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script:

```
!s::send //********************************************************************
```

Alternatively you could also define a hot-string:

```
:://*:://********************************************************************
```

Which would replace //*  with your predefined string...

Comment: where do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Something that you could use is a tool called [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php). It can't really do something like alt+s, but it can convert any text into longer something else (example: "thankyou" to "+{Tab}^{Home}^+{Right}^c{Tab}{BS}Thanks for the email, ^v{BS}." would grab the person's name in an email and say "Thanks for the email, (Name here)." )